# Create empty cells for table date/time line

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to create a timeline grid. The first row is days of the month, which are passed to the view. The second row should be, first the title (fetched from the db) and then empty cells until the end of the table. The next row should start with the title (fetched from the db) followed by the empty cells, etc.

Don't know how to create empty cells and place then next to the title until the end of the table, and then render the next title and repeat the process until all titles are rendered.

Below you find my code:

```
<?php
    $start_date = '2014-09-01';
    $end_date = '2014-10-10';
    $start = new DateTime($start_date);
    $end = new DateTime($end_date);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $days = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
?>
<table border=1 id="table1">
    <tr>      
        <th></th>
        <?php foreach ($days as $day) {
            echo  "<th>". $day->format('D d-m') . "</th>";
        }?>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <?php foreach ($campaign as $row) {
            echo  "<th>". $row->campaign_name . "</th>";
        }?>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
```

The result should be

- first row: cells with the dates
- first column: cells with campaign names
- rest of the table should be filled with empty cells

Right now all campaign names appaer in the second row, instead of below each other.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Snippets don't work with PHP

Comment: Count how many cells you have, subtract count of full cells and then use a for loop to fill the cells.

Comment: `<tr><?php foreach ($campaign as $row)....`, if a `$row` needs to be on its on `<tr>`... it follows the `<tr>` needs to be _inside_ the `foreach`.